# Problems with update Windows 10 on Lumia

Tags: apps, insider-preview

Today I updated to the preview version of Windows 10 and encountered several problems.

Since I got an error the first time which was related to SD card storage, I changed settings that apps are not stored on SD card but on local storage (internal memory).

Than I installed Windows 10 without any problems.

However, I have the following issues:
- All live tiles are disappeared
- All installed apps from the SD card are not shown in the app list
- However, if I search for an application that is previously installed on SD card, the phone redirects me to the Store, where it is shown as already installed. I can start it up, but not install (reinstall) it.

I don't mind to reinstall all apps (although it were like 100-150 in total), but I mind about not being able to install apps anymore, which is the current situation.

Hope someone can help me.

---

Update: I could revert back to 8.1 thanks to a Microsoft Application. It took some time before all my applications were reinstalled, but in the end I only had to fill in all my passwords and authentication information in all applications which took me about 2 to 3 hours.

For me Windows 10 is unusable (even when released), because it does not support storing applications on SD card. Maybe Windows 10.1 (or 11). I hope it will not be a mandatory update/install process when Windows 10 is released officially.

Comment: Windows 10 for phones is still quite buggy. After the you install the preview, if things aren't working properly then you'll have to do a full reset. If you were hoping that everything will "just work" then you're best to wait until the final (or near final) release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus far, my experience with 10 has not being great either.
 I have the *Lumia 830*. 
Too many screen locks that only a reboot get it back.
Trying to unlock during a toast display, the touch screen locks. Receiving an incoming call while in lock mode, sometimes the screen turns unresponsive and don't let you answer the call.

### A hint that makes W10 work better

> All settings -> personalization-> start .
>   Only use "**Show more tiles**" **on**,

setting it to "**off**" makes the phone unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

The unseen SD card is a know bug: it depends on your previous setting before the upgrade to w10. I'll explain better: if you had selected sd card as storage for you pictures on w8.1, you can keep on saving your pictures in the sd card in windows 10. If you inserted a new sd AFTER the upgrade, it won't be seen by the phone.
Also, if you go in the storage setting, you won't be able to see how much free memory is available; Microsoft is well aware of this bug, I hope they'll fix it in the new build that will be out tomorrow, according to rumors and Windows Central.